# ./configure script incorrectly passing a function check for asprintf

Tags: linux, autotools, autoconf

In an autoconf script I have:

```
AC_CHECK_FUNC([asprintf],
    [CONFIGFLAGS+=" -DCB_HAVE_ASPRINTF"],
    []
)
```

And this passes, thus defining `CB_HAVE_ASPRINTF`. But without defining `_GNU_SOURCE` the makefile will fail, so it is incorrect for the configure script to pass this function. What is wrong with it?

This problem is occurring on Linux Mint 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AC_CHECK_FUNC[S]` only does link-time checks, it doesn't check the headers.

Also, it's [documented as being a GNU extension](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf), so you should only try to use it if you defined `_GNU_SOURCE` before the includes or in the command-line.

Comment: OK, I understand the bahviour, and while I should perhaps still check for asprintf, I should also define _GNU_SOURCE. Thanks.